# Implement bit-wise matrix multiplication

Tags: code-golf, math, bitwise, binary-matrix

The [MMIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX) architecture is a fairly simple big-endian RISC design. It has a couple of interesting features, one of them is the `MXOR` instruction, which is what you should implement.

The `MXOR` instruction interprets its arguments (two 64-bit registers) as two 8×8 matrices of bits and performs a matrix multiplication where exclusive-or is used for addition and logical and is used for multiplication.

An argument in binary representation where the leftmost digit is most significant

> a<sub>0</sub> a<sub>1</sub> a<sub>2</sub> … a<sub>63</sub>

is interpreted as a matrix like this:

> a<sub>0</sub> a<sub>1</sub> … a<sub>7</sub>
>   a<sub>8</sub> a<sub>9</sub> … a<sub>15</sub>
>   …
>   a<sub>56</sub> a<sub>57</sub> … a<sub>63</sub>

Your task is to write a function, subroutine or similar in a language of choice which can be evoked from a single-letter name (i.e. `f(x,y)`) that implements this function. The two arguments of the function shall be of equal implementation-defined unsigned 64 bit integer type, the function shall return a value of the same type.

he winner of this competition is the shortest submission (measured in bytes or characters if the language you use uses a meaningful character encoding). You are encouraged to post a readable commented version of your code in addition to the golfed solution so other's can understand how it works.

Comment: Some test cases would be nice.

Comment: Do the input and outputs need to be numbers that correspond to the bitstrings, or can we use lists of bits?

Comment: Am I allowed to use the language's matrix multiplication (if present in the standard lib)?

Comment: Put another way, matrix multiplication where the elements of the matrix are in GF(2).

Comment: @Howard: why not?

Comment: @FireFly Please do not alter the specification without asking and without understanding what it's intent is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### APL, 28 characters

```
f←{2⊥,↑≠.×/{8 8⍴(64⍴2)⊤⍵}¨⍵}
```

Usage:

```
> f 12345678 87654321
3977539
```

You can read it almost literally if you go right-to-left. `(64⍴2)⊤` transforms each argument into 64 bit representation and `8 8⍴` makes an 8x8 matrix out of the results. `≠.×/` then applies the inner product to both arguments, where multiplication `×` and xor `≠` is used. The matrix is then transformed back to vector form `,↑`, before `2⊥` undoes the basis transformation.

Comment: Save 6 bytes by converting to tradfn, swapping `⊤`'s arguments using `⍨`, and flattening with `∊`. Also, you don't need to count the naming of your function in your code length. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdN8I/6L/Ro66ljzq6HnUu0HvUsVy/2kLB4lHvlke9Wx91LXnUu8LMBMgzqj204lHfVJCe/wpgANLKZWhkbGJqZg7UYW5mamJsZAgA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 7):

### x86 machine code, <strike>45</strike> <strike>44</strike> 40 bytes

```
  40072c:       b1 08                   mov    $0x8,%cl
  40072e:       48 c1 c7 08             rol    $0x8,%rdi
  400732:       b5 08                   mov    $0x8,%ch
  400734:       48 0f 6e c6             movq   %rsi,%mm0
  400738:       0f d7 d0                pmovmskb %mm0,%edx
  40073b:       40 20 fa                and    %dil,%dl
  40073e:       7a 01                   jp     400741 <amul+0x15>
  400740:       f9                      stc    
  400741:       48 11 c0                adc    %rax,%rax
  400744:       48 d1 c6                rol    %rsi
  400747:       fe cd                   dec    %ch
  400749:       75 e9                   jne    400734 <amul+0x8>
  40074b:       48 c1 ce 08             ror    $0x8,%rsi
  40074f:       fe c9                   dec    %cl
  400751:       75 db                   jne    40072e <amul+0x2>
  400753:       c3                      retq
```

The code uses two tricky moves.  The first is the `pmovmskb` intsruction which takes every 8th bit of an mmx register and packs them together into an integer register.  Very useful for extracting columns.  The second is the parity flag which is used to accumulate the dot product (the `and`/`jp`/`stc` combo).

Here's the expanded code with comments:

```
    # rowloop
    mov $8, %cl
1:
    rol $8, %rdi    # get next row of A into low 8 bits

    # columnloop
    mov $8, %ch
2:
    # extract first column
    movq    %rsi, %mm0
    pmovmskb    %mm0, %edx

    # dot with current row
    testb   %dil, %dl

    # shift result and add parity bit
    jp  3f
    stc
3:
    adc %rax, %rax

    # shift over columns of B
    rol %rsi

    dec %ch
    jne 2b

    # restore B
    ror $8, %rsi

    dec %cl
    jne 1b
    ret
```

Comment: Looks cool! Very neat solution.

Comment: The use of the parity bit is really ingenious though. Makes the solution so much easier.

Comment: BTW, you can replace `xor %rax,%rax` by `xor %eax,%eax` for one byte. The high byte is zeroed out automatically.  `sub %eax,%eax` might be even shorter.

Comment: You might also want to replace `setnp %dl; lea (%rdx,%rax,2),%rax` by `jnp 1f; stc; 1:adc %rax,%rax` if that improves the size (should bring one byte).

Comment: Oh yes, you can also replace `dec %cl;jne 1b` by `loop 1b` since `%ch` will always be zero when encountering this instruction.

Comment: And finally, you don't need to initialize `%rax` at all—we left shift it's contents 64 times anyway so all the old contents are cleared out.

Comment: Here is an updated version of the code: http://fuz.su/~fuz/src/golf/dotproduct.s

Comment: @FUZxxl: I incorporated your suggestions.  The only one I didn't do is the `loop` suggestion - it doesn't quite work.  If rcx contains high bits on entry, we loop way too many times.  It turns out the result is always correct because we recompute it over and over, but if bit 63 of rcx is set, termination takes a *really* long time.

Comment: Shouldn't `mov $8,%cl` clear the upper 32 bits of `%rcx`? Looping for up to about 2³² extra cycles isn't too bad—should be an extra 20 seconds top.

Comment: @FUZxxl: no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

### GolfScript (<strike>49 48</strike> 45 chars)

This takes a completely different approach to my earlier GolfScript entry, so I think it wants a separate answer.

```
{0{1$M&16.?M/:K*3$K&M*&^@2/@M)/@}255:M*++}:f;
```

It's pure bit-bashing.

If we consider `a` as a series of matrix elements we get

```
a_00 a_01 a_02 a_03 a_04 a_05 a_06 a_07 a_10 a_11 ...
```

Similarly `b`. Now, `c_ij = a_i0 & b_0j ^ a_i1 & b1j ^ ... ^ a_i7 & b7j`. So by grouping over the common index we get

```
c =   (a_00 a_00 ... a_00 a_00 a_10 a_10 ...) & (b_00 b_01 b_02 ... b_07 b_00 b_01 ...)
    ^ (a_01 a_01 ... a_01 a_01 a_11 a_11 ...) & (b_10 b_11 b_12 ... b_17 b_10 b_11 ...)
    ^ ...
  =   (((a >> 7) & 0x0101010101010101) * 0xff) & (((b >> 56) & 0xff) * 0x0101010101010101)
    ^ (((a >> 6) & 0x0101010101010101) * 0xff) & (((b >> 48) & 0xff) * 0x0101010101010101)
    ^ ...
```

That's enough background to be able to explain the code:

```
{                 # Function declaration boilerplate; stack is a b
  0               # Accumulator for the result
  {               # Loop: stack holds a>>k b>>8k partial-sum
    1$M&          #   M holds 255 (see below); get (b>>8k) & 0xff
    16.?M/:K      #   Derive 0x0101010101010101 and store in K
    *             #   Multiply: stack is a>>k b>>8k partial-sum rhs-of-and
    3$K&M*        #   Similarly for a: add lhs-of-and to the stack
    &^            #   Do the pointwise multiplication and addition
    @2/@M)/@      #   Restore loop invariant with a>>=1 and b>>=8
  }255:M*         # Store 255 in M and execute the loop that many times
                  # 8 times suffices to get the correct result; after that b>>8k == 0 and the
                  # partial sum doesn't change. After 64 iterations, a>>k == 0
  ++              # So we can ditch their remnants by adding to the partial sum
}:f;              # Function declaration boilerplate
```

Thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for the observation that `16.?` is equal to `2 64?` (or `2.6??`); since it's one char shorter, I've stolen it. Thanks to [Howard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1490/howard) for suggesting a 2-char improvement which became 48->45.

Comment: Now *that's* an interesting approach. Nice bit magic!

Comment: You can replace `;;` with `*` since `b>>64` is always zero.

Comment: If you directly calculate the result on the stack (instead of collecting terms in an array) you may even save one more char: `{0{1$255:M&16.?M/:K*3$K&M*&^@2/@M)/@}8*+\;}:f;`.

Comment: @Howard, good points both. It's even possible to save one more by shifting `a` far enough right to become zero.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 35 bytes

```
{2{GG#+2b1>8/\}*zm*{z{:&}%:^}%2b}:F
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/) by pasting the following *Code*:

```
{2{GG#+2b1>8/\}*zm*{z{:&}%:^}%2b}:F;  " Define function and clear stack.              ";
12345678 87654321 F                   " Call function.                                ";
```

#### How it works

```
2{      " Do the following twice:                                                     ";
  GG#+  " Add 16 ** 16 = 2 ** 64 to the topmost integer on the stack.                 ";
  2b    " Convert it into an array of its digits in base two.                         ";
  1>    " Discard the first digit.                                                    ";
  8/    " Split into arrays of 8 digits.                                              ";
  \     " Swap the resulting array with the second topmost stack element.             ";
}*      " This converts two 64-bit integers into 8×8 matrices of its base 2 digits.   ";
zm*     " Transpose the second matrix and compute the cartesian product of both.      ";
{       " For each pair (one row of the first and one column of the second matrix):   ";  
  z     " Transpose the array.                                                        ";
  {:&}% " For each array of the array, compute the logical AND of its elements.       ";
  :^    " Compute the logical XOR of the results.                                     ";
}%      " Note that ^ and & are addition and multiplication in GF(2).                 ";
2b      " Convert the array of base 2 digits into and integer.                        ";
```

Comment: `8 ** 8 = 2 ** 24`, surely?

Comment: Of course... `G` is 16, so it's a wrong comment for correct code. Thanks!

Comment: Nice trick, though. If I steal it, I can save 1 char.

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript (65 chars)

```
{[{2.6??+2base(;8/\}2*zip 8*\{{.}7*}%]zip{zip{~&}%{^}*}%2base}:f;
```

This turns out to be similar to BeetDemGuise's Python solution, although it uses more zips and less eval.

Dissection:

```
{
  # Stack: a b (as integers)
  [                  # Start gathering into array for subsequent zip
    {                # Repeat twice:
      2.6??+2base(;  # Convert to 64 bits
      8/             # Break into an 8x8 matrix
      \              # Flip top of stack
    }2*
    # Stack: a b (as matrices)
    # Each cell of the matrix product needs a row of a and a column of b
    zip 8*           # Get 8 copies of columns of b, ordered
                     #   [col_0 col_1 ... col_7 col_0 col_1 ...]
    \{{.}7*}%        # Get 8 copies of rows of a, ordered
                     #   [row_0 row_0 row_0 ... row_7 row_7]
  ]                  # Gather into array
  zip                # Zip: each array entry is now an array [col_j row_i]
  {                  # Map each array item
    zip              # Pair up each bit from col_j with corresponding bit of row_i
    {~&}%            # Multiply the bits in each pair
    {^}*             # Add the products
  }%

  2base              # Convert back from an array of 64 bits to an integer
}:f;                 # Assign to f and don't leave a copy lying about on the stack
```

Answer (score 3):

### J, 50 chars

Here is a version that does not use J's built-in [general matrix product conjunction](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d300.htm) `.`.

```
   f=:#.@,@:(|."1)@(~:/@:*"2 1"1 2|.)&(8 8$]#:~64#2:)
```

#### Testing (with 4×4 matrices)

```
   g=:#.@,@:(|."1)@(~:/@:*"2 1"1 2|.)&(4 4$]#:~16#2:)
   44584 g 28371
46550
```

And the matrices visualized, for manual verification.

```
   (4 4$]#:~16#2:)&.> 44584;28371;46550
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│1 0 1 0│0 1 1 0│1 0 1 1│
│1 1 1 0│1 1 1 0│0 1 0 1│
│0 0 1 0│1 1 0 1│1 1 0 1│
│1 0 0 0│0 0 1 1│0 1 1 0│
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

#### Exploded view

```
                                  &(             ) to each of the arguments,
                                            64#2:    generate 64 2's (radix for below)
                                        ]#:~         decode from radix
                                    8 8$             reshape as 8×8 array
                (              |.)                 reverse the right argument
                       "2 1"1 2                    for each pair of rows,
                      *                              multiply
                    @:                               composed with
                 ~:/                                 xor folded
         (|."1)@                                   reverse each row
      ,@:                                          ravel (flatten array)
   #.@                                             back to binary again
f=:                                                assign function to name 'f'
```

Comment: Instead of `64#2:`, isn't there a shorter construct with `64$2`?

Comment: @FUZxxl no, we can substitute `#` with `$` (they do the same in this case), but we need the 2 to be a verb for the whole paren to be a train. `2:` is a constant verb returning 2.

Comment: A, right. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 - 183

```
def m(a,b):a,b=map(lambda x:'{:064b}'.format(x),[a,b]);r=range(8);return int(''.join(`eval('^'.join(o+'&'+t for o,t in zip(a[8*i:8+8*i],v)))`for i in r for v in[b[j::8]for j in r]),2)
```

This is the first thing that came to my mind and so it can mostly likely be golfed down quite a bit more. In any case, its pretty straight-forward string manipulation:

```
def m(a,b):
    # Convert the integer inputs to their 64bit binary versions.
    a,b=map(lambda x:'{:064b}'.format(x),[a,b])

    n=''
    # For all rows in matrix a...
    for row in [a[8*i:8+8*i] for i in range(8)]:
        # For all columns in matrix b...
        for col in [b[j::8] for j in range(8)]:
            # Get each pair.
            pairs = zip(row, col)

            # Multiply each pair.
            mul_pairs = ['&'.join(z) for z in pairs]

            # XOR them all together.
            result = '^'.join(mul_pairs) 

            # Append the result to n.
            n+=`eval(result)`

    return int(n,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

## J (34)

This *should* work I think. It would be nice if you gave some test cases...

```
f=:~:/ .*&.(8 8&$@(_64&{.) :.,@#:)
```

This works with the test cases supplied in the comments (when changing `8 8` to `4 4` and changing `64` to `16`)

#### Explanation

The whole function can be simplified to the following:

```
F&.G
```

Visual representation:

[image: Under]

What this means: `G` is applied to both arguments. Then `F` is applied with `G x` as its left argument, and `G y` as its right argument. Then, the inverse of `G` is applied to the result of `F`. "Inverse?", you might ask. With inverse I mean a function applied `_1` times, so for example the inverse of `#:` (dec -> bin vector) is `#:^:_1` (or `#.`) (bin vector -> dec).

So, applying this theory, this would be `G`:

- `#:` takes the binary form of the argument
- `_64&{.` takes the last 64 items of the list. When there aren't 64 or
  more items, it will be padded with 0's
- `8 8&$` shapes it to an 8*8 matrix
- `:.,` sets the reverse of `(4 4&$@(_16&{.)` to be just `,`: [ravel](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d320.htm)

and this would be `F`:

- `~:/ .*` is matrix multiplication

Comment: Nope, I have a longer version using `.` that seems to work though.  You need to return the corresponding number of the matrix, and `#:` will have issues with leading zero bits. Also, the space before the `.` is significant (to disambiguate from `/.`). Oh, and you want `~:` (xor) in place of `+` (or take the result modulo 2 manually).

Comment: @FireFly Made some changes, would that work?

Comment: Try these for testcases (4×4 arrays, so change the `8 8` correspondingly): 44584 × 33825 = 44584 (33825 is identity); 44584 × 28371 = 46550.

Comment: What I have is currently `f=:#.@,@(~:/ .*)&(8 8$]#:~64#2:)`, but it's so similar to yours that it'd be weird to post it as its own answer.  Maybe you can work off of that.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some text that explains how it works.

Comment: @FUZxxl Done!​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I think you can shorten this using
`8 8&$ :.,@(64#2)&#:` for the right-hand side.